# Android WebView scroll to bottom

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll

I try to scroll down the page I have in my WebView. Therefore I found the function `.pageDown(true)`. The problem is that this function does not really work for me. Mostly it does not do anything.

Codesnippet:

```
wvChat.loadData(chat_, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
                 wvChat.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        wvChat.pageDown(true);
                     }
                 });
```

Is there another method or is it wrong to use it in onPageFinished?

Comment: not sure..but i think scrollview will help you if you put the webview inside scrollview in your layout.

Answer (score 7):

get the html content height and use [scrollTo(x,y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29)

```
wvChat.loadData(chat_, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
             wvChat.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                 @Override
                 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //use the param "view", and call getContentHeight in scrollTo
                    view.scrollTo(0, view.getContentHeight());
                 }
             });
```

Comment: works better but sometimes it scrolls up to the top not to bottom :o it looks like the keyboard is the problem, is it possible that it can't scroll down when the keyboard is open? because it does change the height of the webview

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution to scroll down large files (much lines) using the scrollTo function. I set a much higher value than the content height can be.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
  {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);     

    Handler lHandler = new Handler();
    lHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {             
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        mWebView.scrollTo(0, 1000000000);
      }
    }, 200);
  } 
});
```

The problem is now, that it does not work for small files (less lines), because the onPageFinished method is called before the WebView has been rendered, so I have to use a delay handle.

Answer (score 3):

```
      wvChat.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                     @Override
                     public void onPageCommitVisible(WebView view, String url) {
                        wvChat.pageDown(true);
                     }
                 });
```

this better, without delay...

Comment: I wonder how this was downvoted when it's the only correct solution

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll `WebView` with Javascript:

```kotlin
private fun scrollMove(contentHeight: Float) {
    val speed = (contentHeight / 100) * 1000
    currentWebView?.evaluateJavascript("\$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$contentHeight},$speed);", null)
}
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From Review.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best solution for scrolling to the bottom

```
   public void scrollToBottom(boolean animate) {
        if (animate) {
            pageDown(true);
        } else {
            scrollTo(getScrollX(), computeVerticalScrollRange());
        }
    }
```

See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/d0ef9df6be5983f6df7e4e050bbad4eb5030e7a2/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwScrollOffsetManager.java#362